# Suppressing output when marshalling nil-able elements with jaxb

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2, jaxb2-maven-plugin

My code is using a provided XSD that has a a mix of nil-able and not nil-able elements:

```
<xs:element name="LOG_TXNDTLLTY" type="PCMSBOOLEANType" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="CAPTURE_ADDRESS" type="PCMSBOOLEANType" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
```

When I marshal an object which has neither of these values then I get a nil being output for the nil-able element

```
<ns2:CAPTURE_ADDRESS xsi:nil="true" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

While I accept that this is technically the most correct output is there a way I can suppress this so the element doesn't appear at all without changing the XSD?

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to remove

```
generateElementProperty="false"
```

from my bindings file